# Count occurrence of all integers in a list

Tags: c#, data-structures

I have a text file with a lot of numbers (500,000+).

I want to add all the unique values to a list and count how many times it occurs in the whole dataset.

So something like:

```
23232: 55656565 times
35354: 45452 times
45454: 74747 times
```

My code in C# can add all occurrences to the list, but can't count the frequency of them:

```
private void CountUnique()
{
    List<Double> source = new List<double>();
    double sourceID = 0;

    StreamReader file = new StreamReader("trace.txt")
    while((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        string[] words = line.split(' ');
        sourceID = double.Parse(words[1]);
        sourceList.Add(sourceID)
    }
}
```

How do I get an output like the one I want?

Comment: You could use a `Dictionary<double, int>` instead, the key is the number and the value is the count. If it exists in the dictionary, increase the count, otherwise add it with a value of 1.

Comment: Completely forgot about that. Excellent idea! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Group the list of doubles, and then place it in a dictionary using the key from the groups and the count of each grouping.

```
Dictionary<double,int> counts = source.GroupBy(d => d)
    .ToDictionary( g => g.Key, g => g.Count());
```

Here is an easy seed for this:

```
var source = Enumerable.Range(0,500)
    .Select(i => ( i  % 6 ) + 0.02).ToList(); // just simple doubles list
```

And here is the output:

[image]

Comment: don't really need that extra projection - you can do this as part of `ToDictionary`

Comment: @BrokenGlass - The projection is a good idea though. Without it the entire database record is brought across the wire before the `.ToDictionary` is executed. With the projection just the required fields are.

Comment: This would not be from an IQueryable though, it is read and already all in memory from a text file.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding the values in dictionary and than update the count as the number reappears in the file. And if it is appearing first time than you can add it to dictionary with count of 1.

```
private void CountUnique()
{
 Dictionary<Double,int> source = new Dictionary<double,int>();
 double sourceID = 0;
StreamReader file = new StreamReader("trace.txt")
while((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
 {
    string[] words = line.split(' ');
    sourceID = double.Parse(words[1]);
    if (sourcedictionary.ContainsKey(sourceID)
    {
         var sourcecount = source[sourceID];
         sourcecount++;
         source[sourceID] = sourcecount;
    }
    else{
            source.add (sourceID, 1);
     }

 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar question as an interview test question.

This question asked to optimize a routine that does this, and calculates average, and median.

I used a [SortedList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132319%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of Dictionary.  This made it easy to calculate a median and give min max values.